# Prove that if $(2+x)/y$ is rational, then $x$ is rational or $y$ is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Full Question: Let $ x,y$ be real numbers with $y$ not equal to $0$. If $(2+x)/y$ is rational, then $x$ is rational or $y $ is irrational.

I'm taking an if $p$ then $(q \lor r)$ and making it a $(p\wedge\neg q)$ then $r$. I've decided to make my "$y$ is irrational" the $q $ so that I'm only dealing with rational numbers.  So my proof now becomes...

Let $x,y$ be real numbers and $y$ does not equal $0$.
Assume $(2+x)/y$ is rational and $y$ is rational.
Prove that $x $ is rational.

So, $y=a/b$ for some $a,b $ integers and $ b$ does not equal $0$.
Then $(2+x)/y = b(2+x)/a$

I get stuck here.  I need to show that $ x=a_n$ integer over and integer.

I also tried $(2+x)/y = c/d$ for some integers $c, d$ and $ d$ does not equal $0$.  But frankly I'm stuck now.

Ugh... will I ever get proofs???

Comment: This it a tiny bit hard to read. Please format your math using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You assumed both $(2+x)/y$ and $y$ are rational. Then their product $(2+x)$ is also rational.

Comment: You assumed both $(2+x)/y = c/d$ and $y =a/b$. Then their product $(2+x)$ is $\frac{ac}{bd}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t = \frac{2+x}{y}$ and solve for $x$ in terms of $y$ and $t$.  Since you are assuming $y$ and $t$ are rational, you will be able to conclude that $x$ is rational from the formula you get.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.  I've been out of school for 12 years and going back to try to get my teachers cert.  I didn't expect math to be such a struggle to regain!  Every time someone explains it, it clicks and seems so simple!